# Tracking changes to code for personal use

Tags: version-control, editor

I usually practise often in my developer edition, and that also involves writing Apex classes as well as components. It happens that on a particular day, I save a class and a few days later, I edit it to add/modify some logic. As a result of this, there's something that I need very badly - being able to see what changes I made in a particular edit. Basically, a kind of version control but for my personal **developer edition** org. Could anyone please suggest me certain options that would help me in easily tracking code changes. Tools like Bitbucket are available for personal use, but I could not get accurate information regarding the ability to track changes easily using that free version just the way it's done in enterprise edition.

In this area related to code editing and tracking, I'm a kind of newbie. So I'd just like to know given I want to track changes in a code, what could be the best options to consider - even if it's some version control tool or any other tool/software which I could use without paying anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A conventional set of tools for "source code first development" that includes tracking changes on Salesforce is:

- GitHub - free
- VSCode IDE - free
- Salesforce VSCode additions - free
- Salesforce SFDX - free
- Scratch orgs - free

There is a learning curve on each of these, but you only need to know the basics of each to start with, so could be set up and working within a few hours. And if you go on to do a lot of development, the time you invest will more than pay pack.

Google for Trailheads and other posts to explore this option.

Comment: Of course, if you don't want to push your changes into a public Git repository, and you only need the changes one machine you can skip GitHub and just use Git locally and consider Fork, Sourcetree or another graphical UI for Git (see https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis/).

Comment: 100% agree - why use a different approach compared with SFDC's own recommended one? Note that in taking this approach you will switch from use of your dev org to use of short lived scratch orgs and with move to a "source of truth" in git rather than on an unversionable org. A total win-win. No longer do you have to worry about "cruft" from previous abandoned experiments - it disappears with the scratch org - but anything you want to keep you simply retrieve and store in git for next time (in master or a feature specific branch). Doing this means you can join a team running, doing it for real.